# Different Problems after Wordpress Migration

Tags: php, wordpress, post, types

I'm currently developing a WordPress website with Custom Post Types and custom search in post type. In localhost everything works fine but when I migrate the website online I get a different kind of problems which I try to list here:

- There are no pages except for Sample Page
- There are no custom posts (CPT are in admin but zero posts)
- Can't import post and CPTs with WordPress Importer
- Can't import post thumbnails
- There are no menus
- Can't see CPTs box in Menu Admin Page
- Get `undefined function pll_current_language()` (Polylang)

As you can see there are a lot of problem which sounds weird, never happened before, it's not my first WordPress website.
Can you help me?
My b-plan would be removing CPT and using normal posts.
Cheers!

Comment: Do You Change `.htaccess`, `wp-config.php`, Urls in `database` and so on.

Comment: I changed wp-config.php and url in database but not .htaccess

Comment: Please Check is there any change in `Rewritebase` in `.htaccess`.

Comment: I have RewriteBase /local-folder-name/

Comment: Do you have same rewritebase in migrated live site?
If Not Just remove it.

Comment: So I have to remove .htaccess from live server?

Comment: Not ` .htaccess` .  Change. `RewriteBase /local-folder-name/ `. to. `RewriteBase /` @MarcoCasarin

Comment: this is my .htaccess, it is correct?

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /ripa-di-meana/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Answer (score 1):

are you sure you import the database from local to online in your phpmyadmin ??

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, the problem was due to file permissions on my host.